# This code works fine when opened with internet explorer but fails to work when i open it with firefox or other browsers

Tags: javascript

This code works fine when running in IE. I get a request asking to allow blocked content due to the use of activeX. But when I run it in firefox and other browsers.. I get nothing. Kindly help.

```
    var httpRequest;
    try  
    {
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();  // Mozilla, Safari, etc
    }
    catch(trymicrosoft)
    {
      try
      {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(oldermicrosoft)
      {
        try
        {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(failed)
        {
          httpRequest = false;
        }
      }
    }
    if(!httpRequest)
    {
      alert('Your browser does not support Ajax.');
      return false;
    }

    //===============================
    // Action http_request
    var finaltxt;
    //do{
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if(httpRequest.readyState == 4)
      if(httpRequest.status == 200)
        {
              var txt = httpRequest.responseText;
              var index = txt.search(/regular/i);
      var index1 = txt.search(/to see hours/i);
      finaltxt = txt.substring(index,index1);
              document.write("<IMG " +"SRC='web2.jpg'>");
              document.write("<br>"+ finaltxt.fontsize(2) + "<br>");
              return finaltxt;
          }

        else
              return finaltxt;
    }
    httpRequest.open('GET','http://xyz',true);
    httpRequest.send(null);
    return finaltxt;
```

Comment: See this article for cross browser issues: http://www.ilinsky.com/articles/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: Use a library like jQuery so you don't have to take care of cross-browser issues.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a javascript library? jQuery would make this a cinch. Maybe this is a school project? Also, 1) document.write() is considered very harmful and 2) element and attribute names (img, src) should be lowercase for better standards compliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch to use a javascript library like jquery that supports multi=browser support.. you will never have to write code like this again..

see the [ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) in particular.

Check out [jquery](http://jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is to be expected. As you are using ActiveX (just for IE - Not Firefox etc). It is a security measure for IE.